# A doubt in the proof of theorem regarding chromatic symmetric functions

Tags: symmetric-functions

The following theorem is due to Stanley.
[image]

I can't understand, in the proof of the theorem, how he got the bottom line equation from the equation above it. Kindly explain it to me. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both sums are over pairs $(\kappa, S)$ where $S \subseteq E$ and $\kappa$ is a coloring monochromatic on components of $G_S$. In the bottom line we group the pair by taking any coloring $\kappa$ and looking at all $S \subseteq E$ so that $\kappa$ is monochromatic on components $G_S$. In the line above we look at any $S \subseteq E$ then take all colorings $\kappa$ which are monochromtic on components of $G_S$. Note that $\kappa$ is monochromatic on all components of $G_S$ if and only if $\kappa$ is monochromatic on all edges in $S$.

Comment: No problem! It’s a simple little switch, but I remember having to take some time first reading it. And it’s a great formula for the chromatic symmetric function :)

Comment: Yes :). It is a great formula. Very helpful in computations.